# ansible-inventory not working properly with ec2.py when using --profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I was using the follwoing command to import the inventory from aws and it worked well:

```
ansible-inventory -i /etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py --list -y > $some_dic
```

now, I want to use specific aws credentials so I modified the command as follwoing:

```
/etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py --list --profile my-profile
```

which works fine.

However, when I put it all togeather it doesn't work

```
ansible-inventory -i /etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py --list --profile my-profile -y > $some_dic
```

error:

```
ansible-inventory: error: unrecognized arguments: --profile
```

any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`ansible-inventory` command tries to parse all the options including `--profile` which it doesn't have.

`/etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py --list --profile my-profile` executes `ec2.py` with `--profile` option but when the same `ec2.py` is passed to `ansible-inventory` using `-i` option that file itself becomes a parameter for `ansible-inventory` command.

Though, haven't tried myself, you can try setting `AWS_PROFILE` and then execute the command similar to what [described here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2).

Also have a look at the documentation for available options of [ansible-inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-inventory.html).